# Exporting .psd to .jpeg changes CMYK to RGB?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, printing, rgb, cmyk

I don't know much about Photoshop. I created a business card in RGB profile but the printer needs it as CMYK.

I therefore just went to "Mode", changed it to CMYK 16 Bit and thought that was it, but whenever I export it as a JPEG it is always saving with an RGB colour space.

Any ideas how I can export as a CMYK?

Answer (score 1):

It's best **not** to export it as JPEG for printing. See [here](http://help.lockergnome.com/office2/JPG-CMYK-export--ftopict501273.html) for some good tips and discussion. I hope you mean a printing service when you say "printer" rather than an actual printer. If so, find a good printing service that accepts your Photoshop file directly without asking you to export it to **lossy** formats such JPEG!

PS: Please Google at least a bit before asking ;D